# How to nest DataSet table data by table name in XML?

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

Please note that this question does not relate to the nesting of parent-child data across tables/data sets.

In the ADO.Net DataSet, there are two methods to extract the data as XML (I am using [GetXml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.getxml?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Data_DataSet_GetXml), but [WriteXml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.writexml?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Data_DataSet_WriteXml_System_String_System_Data_XmlWriteMode_) produces the same).  Suppose a database call returns the results of these two statements as a DataSet:

```
SELECT name, surname FROM [Users];
SELECT color FROM [Colors];
```

I then export the data as follows...

```
DataSet ds = MyLogic.GetDataSet();
ds.Tables[0].ColumnMapping = MappingType.Attribute;
ds.Tables[1].ColumnMapping = MappingType.Attribute;
string s = ds.GetXml();
```

The data is expressed like this:

```
<NewDataSet>
   <Table0 name="Bob" surname="Smith" />
   <Table0 name="John" surname="Doe" />
   <Table0 name="Jane" surname="Doe" />
   <Table1 color="Red" />
   <Table1 color="Blue" />
<NewDataSet>
```

Is it possible to use nested XML nodes to differentiate each table structure?   Like this:

```
<NewDataSet>
   <Table0>
     <row name="Bob" surname="Smith" />
     <row name="John" surname="Doe" />
     <row name="Jane" surname="Doe" />
   </Table0>
   <Table1>
     <row color="Red" />
     <row color="Blue" />
   </Table1>
<NewDataSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

An attempt to answer my own question while anyone else might have a better solution.  Will delete if a better answer is posted.

Crude and contains unneccessary  tags, but can be cleaned up...

```
string s = string.Empty;
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
{
    sw.Write("<ExportedData>");
    foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
    {
        sw.Write(string.Format("<{0}>", dt.TableName));
        dt.WriteXml(sw, XmlWriteMode.IgnoreSchema, false);
        sw.Write(string.Format("</{0}>", dt.TableName));
    }
    sw.Write("</ExportedData>");
    s = string.Concat(s, sw.ToString());
}
```